# video js IE 9, 10 do not play video

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I´m sure this question is asked already several times and I tried many of the different solutions like preload none, add the AddType things to the htaccess, etc.

Still all browsers work, just IE9 and IE10 do never play the video. The console shows this error:
VIDEOJS:ERROR:(CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.[object Object]

What makes me really wonder is that the video on http://www.videojs.com/ does not play in IE9, 10 as well. Does anyone have the same? Or is just my IE weird (I use Parallels Desktop on Mac with Win 8).

here is the html code:

```
  <video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
                               preload="auto"
                               autoplay="autoplay"
                               loop="loop"
                               poster="poster.jpg">
                            <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                            <source src="video.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
                            <source src="video.webm" type='video/webm' />
                        </video>
```

Many thanks for any advice.
Flo

Comment: The video at http://www.videojs.com plays in IE for me.

Comment: Works for me too. It might be a limited version of windows that doesn't have the right codecs installed.

Comment: You could try creating a standard video tag, and see if that works. If it does, then it is a video.js issue. `<video src="Some_Video.mp4" controls></video>`

Comment: Can you post you code?  Did you specify a different techOrder?

Comment: what do you mean with techOrder? I added the code in the question.

Comment: thx, i finally tested on other windows machines and it worked everywhere. but still not sure why it did not work under win 8 running on parallels desktop

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Try updating your adobe flash player pluggin.  This have fixed my problem. My video js player is now working on IE 9,10, may work on later versions but i haven't checked.
Also check what encoding is supported by video to run on IE browsers.